# Is there a way to pass a className to a component in react-markdown?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, markdown, jsx

I'm trying to pass a className to a component in react-markdown.

For example,

```
<ReactMarkdown source='test' />
```

Will result in

```
<p>test</p>
```

How can I get to

```
<p className='testClass'>test</p>
```

Comment: `ReactMarkdown` has `className` `prop`. Have you tried `<ReactMarkdown source='test' className='testClass' />`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using `renderers` attribute from `ReactMarkdown` library.

Try something as the following:

```
const CustomParagraph = ({ children }) => <p className="testClass">{children}</p>

const Markdown = () => {
  return (
    <ReactMarkdown
      source="test"
      renderers={{ paragraph: (props) => <CustomParagraph {...props} /> }}
    />
  )
}
```

Here is official definition of renderers:

> **Renderers** - object An object where the keys represent the node type
> and the value is a React component. The object is merged with the
> default renderers. The props passed to the component varies based on
> the type of node.

https://github.com/rexxars/react-markdown